# Section numbering conflicts in latex

Tags: sectioning, arabic, algorithmic

I am using the following code in latex (llncs template) to write a paper. I am using xpretocmd to avoid conflicts between arabtex and algorithmic but the problem is that once I solved this conflict by adding xpretocmd I lost section numbering.

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{llncs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\algorithmic}{\let\AND\relax\let\OR\relax\let\NOT\relax}{}{}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosam Hammady explains the solution at http://blog.hammady.net/2008/03/latex-problem-integrating-arabtex-with.html:

> ArabTeX redefines the section formatting command `\section` using
>   `\renewcommand` in `asect.sty`. So I disabled the inclusion of such
>   file in `apatch.sty` by commenting the following:
>
> ```
> %\UsePackage {asect} % load LaTeX extensions for Arabic sections.
> ```
>
> For a normal LaTeX installation, all files exist in
>   `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/arabtex/`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the belkebir's answer but simpler:

Create an empty file named `asect.sty` in the folder where your paper is.

This file will be loaded instead of the one that `apatch.sty` expects. This is the same as commenting out the line in `apactch.sty` but does not require altering system files.

Comment: It worked for me in overleaf, thaaaanks.