# arabtex library delete sections numbers in Spring template

Tags: font-encodings, arabic

I'm using Springer template which is the one in the following link: https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines

To download the template: ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip

My problem is that, when I add arabtex library the sections numbers disappeared.

Following the solution by this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120291/arabic-in-latex), I added these in the beginning:

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
```

and I added "\setcode{utf8}" after "\begin{document}" line.

But then, the sections numbers disappeared.

Comment: @KJO , yes these are the same instructions in all the templates. But it depends on the research conference to allow the edition. Anyway, this is not my question, I only want to add arabic text.

Comment: I already did it, I added the Arabic text, and it appeared perfectly, but the sections' numbers disappeared. So, I think the template can support the utf-8.

Comment: Why not use `lualatex` or `xelatex` to compile `samplepaper.tex` with either `arabluatex` or `arabxetex` to insert Arabic?

Comment: @Robert Alessi,I don't have idea of what you are mentioning .. could u add an example?

Comment: @Ghanem I added one example below.  It uses `lualatex`, but you can achieve the same result with `arabxetex` and `xelatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty file named `asect.sty` in the folder where your paper is.
This question is also discussed [here on TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225442/section-numbering-conflicts-in-latex/232842#232842).

Comment: Yes right, I solved it in this way, but I forgot to add the answer here :D

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  The following example uses `lualatex` and `arabluatex`. Just compile this file with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` and do not use `inputenc` because `lualatex` is natively unicode-aware.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabluatex}
\SetArbEasy

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection Sample}
Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

Subsequent paragraphs, however, are indented.

\subsection{`arabtex' input scheme}
\begin{arab}
  'inna 'abI kAna mina 'l-muqAtilaTi wa-kAnat 'ummI min `u.zamA'i
  buyUti 'l-zamAzimaTi
\end{arab}

\subsection{Unicode input}
\begin{txarab}
  إِنَّ أَبِي كَانَ مِنَ المُقَاتِلَةِ وَكَانَت أُمِّي مِن عُظَمَاءِ بُيُوتِ الزَّمَازِمَةِ
\end{txarab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: they didn't appear. BTW, I'm using overleaf. Another question, how do you convert the arabic sentence to this format: 'inna 'abI kAna mina ..?

Comment: What didn't appear? Try to select the `lualatex` compiler: click once on the `Menu` of Overleaf (top left of the window), then go to `Settings` and select `lualatex` there.  Finally, recompile your document.  As for the conversion from `arabtex` input scheme to unicode, it is taken care of by `arabluatex`.  You will find the documentation here: https://ctan.org/pkg/arabluatex

Comment: I forgot to mention that `arabtex` and `arabxetex` are also able to convert `arabtex` ASCII input scheme to unicode.  As a matter of fact, the former invented this.